# Is there a way to get the IP Ranges of Tmobile and Time Warner Cable networks for whitelisting on my NAS device

Tags: security, ip, nas, whitelist

Is there a ip range for tmobile or time warner cable that is public so we can use it for white listing when accessing our NAS device?

Comment: Any range of addresses they might owned is guaranteed to change in the future.  There are websites that make this information to a point, but that information is not static, and is guaranteed to change in the future.  This information would be even more variable if you are talking about IPv4 instead of IPv6

Comment: What are these sites that posts this information? Mainly looking for IPv4